# concatenatenation of slug and id with rails link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following `link_to` sub_category is a slug title(generated by friendly_id) stored in my db table

How can i have the `id:` with slug and the `id` as well. I have tried something like this but it is a syntax error.

```
<%= link_to sub_category.name, controller: :posts, action: :product, id: sub_category."#{id}" %>
```

How can i solve it

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<%= link_to sub_category.name, controller: :posts, action: :product, id: sub_category.send("#{id}") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not `sub_category.id` ? instead of `sub_category."#{id}"`